# In Singapore, how much does an average person use a car?

Tags: automobiles, singapore

Sorry if this is off topic, I don’t know where to put this question.

I’m doing a project for the First LEGO League and I need to know how many times a car owner, in Singapore, uses their car to compare how many times the SMRT buses are used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel.

Comment: Where can I put this then?

Comment: @Anvay It is not the case that every question will fit on (at least) one Stack Exchange site. Stack Exchange sites are topic-centred and if a site for a certain topic does not exist you will find your question accepted nowhere across the network. I remembered that there is a motoring SE, but that has *maintenance and repair* as part of its name so it probably won’t be allowed there either.

Answer (score 1):

I live in Singapore. Car ownership is prohibitively expensive for an average Singaporean resident (Artificially made so). Public transport is very convenient, cheap and affordable. Network is all over SG. So, most people use public transport.

For car owners, they can afford and mostly uses car. But parking and everything related to car is expensive.

Comment: That doesn’t really answer my question. I asked for how many times does the average person in Singapore use their cars.

Comment: Indeed, this is the answer to a different question.

Comment: @Anvay The average person in Singapore does not have a car.

Comment: @Anvay Define the ‘average person’. What research have you done already? Eg Have you tried searching for statistics online eg on the SMRT bus website? Or even ‘how many cars in Singapore’ and ‘what’s the population of Singapore’.

Comment: Yes I’ve done all of that. I mean average car owner. Sorry.

Comment: I also know that the SMRT buses are used 6,000,000 times a day and there are 975,000 cars and 5,000 buses. I couldn’t find the statistics for how many times an average singaporean car driver uses their car a day.